# Can SCons keep track of linking dependencies?

Tags: c, build, scons

I'm currently working on a C project with one main executable and one executable for each unit test. In the SConstruct file I specify the dependencies for each executable, something like

```
env.Program(['Main.c', 'Foo.c', 'Bar.c', 'Baz.c', ...])
env.Program(['FooTest.c', 'Foo.c', 'Baz.c', ...])
env.Program(['BarTest.c', 'Bar.c', 'Baz.c', ...])
...
```

This, however, is error prone and inelegant since the dependencies could just as well be tracked by the build tool, in this case SCons. How can I improve my build script?

Comment: This is basically the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18141648/1158895

Comment: You could improve this by using libraries.

Comment: @Brady So the question then is why automatic tracking of linking dependencies hasn't been implemented in SCons (or any other build tool that I know of).

Comment: A build tool should never work in such a low level to read source files and figure out the includes hence dependencies.

Comment: @lzprgmr But that's what Scons does, whether you like it or not. What it doesn't do is to sort out the linking dependencies.

Comment: Ah, you are right, not like premake or cmake, which genereate makefile for build, scons is a replacement of make, so it needs to know the dependency between cpp -> header, which means it have to read into the source

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is some sort of tool that
1) Looks at the headers you include
2) Determines from the headers which source files need building
3) Rinse and repeat for all the source files you've just added

Once it's done that it'll have to look over the tree it has generated and try and squish some of that into sensible libraries, assuming you haven't done that already (and looking at the tone of both the questions, that exercise seems to have been viewed as academic, rather than a standard part of good software development).

There might be some mileage in a tool that says "You've included header A/B.h, so you'll need libA in your link line" but even that is going to have plenty of gotchas depending on how different people build and link their libraries.

But what you've asked is asking how to define a build script that writes a build script. It's something you should be doing for yourself.

Comment: I am primarily concerned with the object files, not the libraries. To determine which object files need to be linked together should be almost trivial given the dependency tree that SCons already uses.

Comment: only in the situation that you have guaranteed precisely one header file per source code file (generally not terribly good practice as you should have one source file per function) and you have no libraries. This is not that common a situation

Comment: As long as there is only one implementation of a module I use only one .c file for it (with the same base name as the header file). As far as I know this is the convention. SCons could then automatically link with each object file `foo` corresponding to `foo.h`/`foo.c` if the target depends on these. Libraries would still need to be specified manually.

Comment: But I see your point; if there is more than one implementation file corresponding to a header file the build tool cannot know which of these to link with.

Comment: that is 'a' convention, and honestly, it's a pretty bad one. There is also a convention that you have *one* function per source code file. This makes for much leaner executables and eradicates a raft of nasty link time dependencies. It is going to be incredibly tedious for a build system to work that out.